# robust::glmRob (method 'mallows') vs robustbase::glmrob (method 'Mqle') - very different estimates

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, robust

I want to apply a robust logistic regression in R and I tried the functions `robust::glmRob` (using the method `mallows`) and `robustbase::glmrob` (method `Mqle`, which fits a generalized linear model using Mallows or Huber type robust estimators, according to the authors).

I don't understand much about those estimators, but I would assume that the estimates would be similar. However, I came quite surprised with the results I get with each function for the same model.

Using `robust::glmRob`:

```
rm1 <- robust::glmRob(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6,
                family = binomial(),
                dados_std,
                method = "mallows")
summary(rm1)

Call: robust::glmRob(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, family = binomial(), 
    data = dados_std, method = "mallows")
Deviance Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7305 -1.1256  0.7789  1.0235  1.4008 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     0.4245     0.4189  1.0133   0.3109
X1              0.1621     0.4646  0.3489   0.7272
X2             -0.1290     0.4700 -0.2745   0.7837
X3             -0.4512     0.4891 -0.9225   0.3563
X4              0.5052     0.5248  0.9626   0.3358
X5             -0.2555     0.4867 -0.5249   0.5997
X6             -0.1752     0.4476 -0.3914   0.6955

(Dispersion Parameter for binomial family taken to be 1 )

    Null Deviance: 30.97 on 27 degrees of freedom

Residual Deviance: 29.33906 on 21 degrees of freedom

Number of Iterations: 4 

Correlation of Coefficients:
              (Intercept)     X1            X2        X3
X1             0.057559                                      
X2            -0.040466   -0.144392                          
X3            -0.012770    0.013950      0.272322            
X4             0.125793    0.027971     -0.003343 -0.170828  
X5             0.008357   -0.128829     -0.125688  0.281676  
X6            -0.006110   -0.030635     -0.037557  0.162867  
                  X4           X5
X1
X2
X3
X4
X5             0.015556                
X6            -0.049577     0.359670


car::vif(rm1)
      X1            X2            X3            X4            X5     
1.061469      1.183564      1.282676      1.044061      1.324446      
      X6
1.157015
```

Using `robustbase::glmrob`:

```
rbm1 <- robustbase::glmrob(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6,
                      family = binomial(),
                      dados_std,
                      method = "Mqle")
summary(rbm1)

Call:  robustbase::glmrob(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, family = binomial(), data = dados_std, method = "Mqle") 


Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      86.29     608.89   0.142    0.887
x1              179.83    1291.67   0.139    0.889
x2              -90.82     661.93  -0.137    0.891
x3              -78.10     562.45  -0.139    0.890
X4              104.47     763.18   0.137    0.891
X5             -111.49     799.05  -0.140    0.889
X6               28.25     219.70   0.129    0.898
Robustness weights w.r * w.x: 
 4 observations c(4,5,15,28)
     are outliers with |weight| <= 2e-08 ( < 0.0036); 
 24 weights are ~= 1.

Number of observations: 28 
Fitted by method ‘Mqle’  (in 48 iterations)

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

No deviance values available 
Algorithmic parameters: 
   acc    tcc 
0.0001 1.3450 
maxit 
   50 
test.acc 
  "coef"



car::vif(rbm1)
        X1            X2            X3            X4            X5     
178.419224     69.151432    105.426841     87.115956     67.268833      
      X6
7.502918
```

Some questions:

1. Why are the estimates (and vif) so different?
2. How to know each one is the better method?
3. It is possible that the number of IV (n=6) are too much for such a small sample (n=28)?

I'm so confused that any explanation would be appreciated

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The answer to (3), which I think you can guess, also answers (1) and (2).

Comment: @whuber, in that case why aren't the vif and the estimates of `robust::glmRob` affected? the same sample is used (n=28)

Comment: The estimates are found with a numerical method.  It is likely that the optimum hasn't been found by either function.  The VIF is a property of the explanatory variables and can usually be computed in a numerically stable manner.